# Most efficient way to compare elements of an array depending on previous element in python

Tags: python

Here is my problem.
I have two numpy arrays of very big length of data type numpy.uint8.
These array contains only 0 and 1 elements. (Maybe I could change the data type to make it faster ?)
One array is the reference (ref) and the other one is the checked (chk)
I want to compare the two arrays by chunk of 500 consecutive elements and I only check if previous element from ref is 0

What is the fastest way to do that ?

Currently I iterate through array

```
prev_bit = 0
chk_bit_cnt = 500
for k in range(chk_bit_cnt):
    if ref[k-1] == prev_bit:
        if ref[k] == chk[k]:
            num_pass += 1
        else:
            # Early exit
            num_err += 1
            if num_err >= err_th:
                return False
```

But I feel like there is a more efficient way

Comment: I don't see any indication that you're setting `prev_bit` in your loop. Is this correct? Do you really just look for "compares equal after 0"?

Comment: Also, at the beginning of the array (index 0) when you do `k - 1` you're getting `ref[-1]` which is the last element. Is this a bug, or what you want?

Comment: Your code does not contain the number `500`, so I'm not sure how it matches your description.

Comment: So the typical sequences I m testing are like prbs sequences (7, 15, ..). If k == 0 then previous bit I want to check is the last one yes. I want to wrap around. Typical check I want to do is to check if I can find some match between prbs7 seq and prbs7 seq shifted by X

Comment: Should `prev_bit` always be 0? Side note: for clarity, it's best to invert your if conditions and use `continue`s. Side side note: you might get a slight increase in performance if you convert to python lists first via `.tolist()`.

Comment: prev_bit could be 0 or 1. What do you mean by inverting the if conditions ? Can you give me a snippet ?

Answer (score 0):

(Note: none of this is tested.)

Try using `numpy.roll` to rotate the array by one:

```
rotated_ref = np.roll(ref, 1)
```

Now you can compare items element-wise:

```
ref_chk_equal = (ref == chk)
```

Set up a target array:

```
results = np.zeros(ref.shape)
```

Use `logical_xor` only when zero: (note: you could use bitwise xor, maybe faster)

```
np.logical_xor(ref_chk_equal, rotated_ref, results, where=(rotated_ref == 0))
```

This should only assign to results when rotated_ref is 0, otherwise leave 0 in results. It should produce the xor of the values, which when one items is zero is always the other item.

Comment: I'm not getting why you do a xor between ref_chk_equal and rotated_red. ref_chk_equal should already containing the equal results and you are filtering with the where arguments ?

Answer (score 0):

I thought all the day long to your passionating problem

```py
import numpy as np

ref_chk = np.array([0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1])  
new_chk = np.array([0,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0])

nor_chk = ref_chk ^ new_chk
print(nor_chk)
# [0 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1]

Err = 0
for i in range(len(ref_chk)-1):
    if ref_chk[i] == 0:
        Err += nor_chk[i+1]
print(Err)
# Err : 3 --> positions = [0,4,5] in ref_chk
## if Err >= err_th:
##     return False
```